# Should I go further with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have experience with Core Java only and seen following tutorials how Spring MVC works -

1. What is MVC?
2. Basic theory of Dispatcher Servlet , Handler Mapping.

Now , I am facing difficulties writing the code. 
Should I go in the flow of Spring MVC or I should dig more into JSP , Servlets etc before going to Spring MVC.?

Comment: @acdcjunior - 
1) Unable to understand the dependencies that are required during the program
2) Managing the xml files , for example , like pom.xml
3) Configuring Apache Tomcat as the server in Eclipse

Comment: @acdcjunior - I have downloaded Maven plugin for that. But , during writing the code , I dont know which dependency can come in handy.

Comment: For (1) and (2), getting a Maven plugin is good, but you should learn what Maven is before using it. A book or a medium-length tutorial on the subject will get you trough. (3) To get to know what Apache Tomcat is and how to set it up, it is mandatory that you know JSP and Servlets well. Also, to know what dependencies are necessary to your web application, once again, get to study Servlets and JSP a little and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now , I am facing difficulties writing the code. Should I go in the flow of Spring MVC or I should dig more into JSP , Servlets etc before going to Spring MVC.?

Dig more.

Servlets are pretty much what Spring MVC is built on. If you can't understand them properly, you'll never really know what you are doing.

JSP can be used as the View component of Spring MVC and, of course, knowing it well is necessary to use it well.

> Please suggest me a book for Spring MVC other than Spring in Action.

Stackoverflow is no place for asking this kind of thing (for that, I believe this question will be closed): understand why [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations).

But, since we are here already, following my personal (private exclusive mine and for today - as in "it may change tomorrow" - only :) opinion, I suggest [Pro Spring MVC: With Web Flow (Professional Apress)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430241551)